# Wordpress Admin Bar: change background color for frontend users

Tags: wordpress, plugins, content-management-system

Trying to change the background color of the WP admin bar for logged-in frontend users. All code must reside within a plugin, not a theme. I managed to remove nav entries of the admin bar, but targeting the admin bar CSS via my plugins' CSS file doesn't seem to have any effect. So I assume to target the admin bar CSS in the frontend I would need to handle its CSS through my plugins PHP? Some help is appreciated, really have no idea how to approach this :)

Admin bar looks like this right now:

admin bar:

[image]

CSS (display: none removes the bar in the admin area, but not in the frontend, which is fine):

```
#wpadminbar {
  display: none;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

PHP (removes links):

```
    function remove_admin_bar_links() {
  global $wp_admin_bar;
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');          
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('about');            
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wporg');            
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('documentation');    
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('support-forums');   
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('feedback');         
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('site-name');       
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('view-site');       
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('updates');         
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('comments');         
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('new-content');      
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('w3tc');             
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');       
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('customize'); 
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

Comment: please attach a screenshot of where or what elements you are trying to change... also could you please show of what have you already tried....

Comment: Hi Sajjad, updated the post. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Solved, turns admin bar grey in the frontend:


`add_action('wp_head', 'change_bar_color');
add_action('admin_head', 'change_bar_color');
function change_bar_color() {
?>
<style>
#wpadminbar{
background: #cccccc !important;
}
</style>
<?php
}`